# No route matches missing required keys: [:id] when running RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In a Rails (5.1) app I have the following routes

```
edit_admin_topics_active GET /admin/topics/active/:id/edit(.:format) admin/topics/active#edit
admin_topics_active PATCH  /admin/topics/active/:id(.:format) admin/topics/active#update
                    PUT    /admin/topics/active/:id(.:format) admin/topics/active#update
```

The following controller

```
class Admin::Topics::ActiveController < Admin::TopicsController
 ...

  def edit
    @topic = Topic.find_by_slug(params[:id])
  end

  def update
   ...  
  end
...
end
```

And the following view

```
#app/views/topics/active/edit
<%= form_for @topic, url: admin_topics_active_path(@topic) do |f|  %>
  <%= render 'form', f: f, topic: @topic %>
<% end %>
```

Everything works fine in development, however when I try to run the following (simplified) spec (RSpec 3.7)

```
RSpec.feature 'Update a topic', type: :feature do
  let(:topic) { create(:topic) }

  scenario 'the updated topic is included in the list of topics' do
    visit edit_admin_topics_active_path(topic)
    submit_form
    expect(page).to have_content(topic.code)
  end
end
```

I get

> ActionView::Template::Error:
>          No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/topics/active", :id=>nil}, missing required keys:
>   [:id]

Any idea what this happens?

Comment: is your `topic` being created ?, maybe it is failing due to some validations you have in your model. Put a `binding.pry` before `visit ...` and inspect `topic.errors`, see if there are any.

Comment: If you're using FactoryGirl you should try running `FactoryGirl.lint` to make sure your factory is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The model is created.
```#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007fb7851482c0 @base=#<Topic id: 1, code: "CODE1", edition: 1, created_at: "2018-04-12 15:27:07", updated_at: "2018-04-12 15:27:07", slug: "code1", description: "lorem ipsum", owner_job_description_id: 1, kind_id: 1, frequency: nil, state: "active">, @messages={}, @details={}>``` I also see the attributes when I access the HTMl file saved by RSpec.

Comment: Try `visit edit_admin_topics_active_path(topic.slug)`

Comment: @Vasilisa tried and got the same error.

Comment: The issue is not related to the edit action, but to the update. I can visit  `edit_admin_topics_active_path`. but when I try to submit the form I get the error.

Comment: In your controller you're using `find_by_slug`. But when you pass a record to the polymorphic routes helper it calls `.to_param` which default to the id attribute. What you can do is `where('id OR slug = ?', params[:id]).first!` to allow the record to be fetched by either or.

Comment: Or perhaps the error is caused by a custom `to_param` method?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. However, nothing seems to be the cause. Keep in mind that everything works on development.